# JS - argument gets multiplied by 10 inside an async function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, canvas

I'm trying to write an async function to operate a canvas animation about upwards projectile motion (the height in every time step after you throw something straight up).
My plan was to draw one line, then wait for a few miliseconds, then draw again.

My wait function:

```
function wait(ms){
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

And my draw function (h0 is the base height, v0 is base velocity):

```
async function draw(h0, v0){
    let y = 310.0 - h0;
    for (let t = 0; t <= 10; t++){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(300, y);
        y = 310 - (h0 + (v0*t - (g * t*t) / 2));
        ctx.lineTo(300, y);
        ctx.stroke();
        await wait(65);
    }
}
```

I'm subtracting from 310, because 310 is my canvas height. Canvas pixels are counted from top left, and that's inconvenient (I wanted it operated from bottom left, like a coordinate system).

So now the problem: the *y* variable is computed... somewhat unexpectedly? I can't even describe this.
For example, in the beginning (assume *t* = 0, *h0* = 47, *v0* = 13, *g* = 9.81) *y* should be equal to 263, but it's equal to -160.

Seems like the *h0* argument has changed from 47 to 470 for no apparent reason just for this line - trying `console.log(h0)` outputs correct 47. Hardcoding the *h0* value: `y = 310 - (47 + (v0*t - (g * t*t) / 2));` also gives the correct result.

So the question is - what the heck is going on here and how to fix this? I've never seen a bug like this.

Comment: Sort of minor point, but what's the point in putting the `setTimeout` in a promise? Seems like you can use `setInterval` or (better yet for animation) `requestAnimationFrame` directly with less indirection.

Comment: Completely forgot about rAF. I looked for a function that would stop the program for a fixed number of miliseconds, and got this one. It worked for other animations I've created for this project, so I didn't wonder about it too much.

Comment: I can't reproduce the reported behavior (after removing the lines referring to `ctx`), neither in a snippet here on SO, nor in an external REPL. Unless one of the `ctx` methods is modifying `y`, the behavior you're describing seems unlikely. I suggest that you add a working snippet to your question that reproduces the behavior.

Comment: Here's the whole source file. It's in Polish though, I hope you won't get lost. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xD0mP9H61M-vn9gdsb9VqSO5feA3H4ul